# Evitar que una letra se repita mas de tres veces continuas

Tags: javascript

Esta función no me permite escribir continuamente mas de tres veces la misma letra, el problema es, que tengo que presionar la tecla borrar para poder seguir escribiendo una letra distinta, como puedo  aplicar el bloqueo, solo para esa letra que se repite, no así para las demás.

```
function comprobar(esto){
      var record=0;
      var igual=1;
      var letraRecord
      var b=0;
      var letra="";

      for (a=1;a<esto.length;a++){

        if (esto.charAt(a)==esto.charAt(b)){
          igual=igual+1;
          letra=esto.charAt(a);
        } else {
          if(igual>record){
          record=igual;
          letraRecord=letra;
          }
          igual=1;
        }
        b=a;
        }

      if(igual>record){
      record=igual;
      letraRecord=letra;
      }
      if (record>2) {
        return false;
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con una expresión regular.
La función de abajo te devuelve un booleano si ha encontrado 3 caracteres iguales pasandole un string.

Con [a-zA-Z] le digo que solo capture las letras de la 'a' a la 'z' ya sea minuscula o mayuscula.

y con \1{2,} es para conseguir 3 veces o más de forma continua partiendo del último caracter.

```
function hasRepeatedLetters(str) {
    var regularExpresion= /([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}/;
    var result = regularExpresion.test(str);
    return result;
}

console.log(this.hasRepeatedLetters("dfff"));
console.log(this.hasRepeatedLetters("dffdd"));
console.log(this.hasRepeatedLetters("dffdfwww"));
```

Comment: rgr88 , gracias por tu colaboración, pero al pasar la funcion hasRepeatedLetters  al input con la opción  onkeypress="return hasRepeatedLetters(event)", bloquea todas las teclas. quizás estoy haciendo algo mal.

Comment: hasRepeatedLetters le tienes que pasar un String no el evento.
Ej: var isRepeated = hasRepeatedLetters("abbbc")
No sé como tienes el resto de código